# why cant we divide an array say 5 times in a merge sort?

Tags: sorting, merge

in merge sort, we always divide the array twice. why dont we divide it more than twice ?? and which is better among heap sort and merge sort ?I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not try it and see. Write a merge sort that splits into 5 pieces instead of 2, and test its performance. The best way to learn is to try.

It has no effect on computational complexity, so the improvement is at most a constant factor. You reduce the number of merge passes by a factor of lg(5) ≈ 2.3, but the merging step now requires a priority queue, which is going to be more than 2.3 times slower than the single comparison used by a two-phase merge.

Dividing into more than 2 pieces is known as [polyphase merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphase_merge_sort), and it is used when you need to minimize the number of merge passes.

Comment: Thank you :) I just wanted to look at Wat all tradeoffs arise on increasing d number of splits . :)

Comment: `no effect on computational complexity` no effect on *asymptotic* complexity. `Dividing into more than 2 pieces is known as` *`polyphase`* `merge sort` [multi-way merge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm#Direct_k-way_merge)

Comment: @greybeard  No it isn't. Polyphase *sort-merge* uses a Fibonacci distribution, not just any old thing above N = 2.

Comment: (@user207421 The text I had "code" styled (monospaced, grey background in my browser) is a quote from the post; *I* suggested to use `multi-way merge` instead.)